# Checking a radio input field by its value

Tags: jquery, html

I have searched for the answer but all I got couldn't solve my problem.

I want to `checked` a radio `input` like this

```
<input type="radio" name="field" value="a" />
<input type="radio" name="field" value="b" checked />
<input type="radio" name="field" value="c" />
<a href="javascript:;">cancel</a>

// jQuery
$("a").click(function(){
    var checked = "b";
    $('input').each(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        if(value == checked){
            $(this).attr('checked', true);
        } else {
            $(this).attr('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Now this is what I want to achieve, the default value is "b" so if a user clicks "a" or "c" and wants to return the value back to "b" without clicking "b" and clicks the link I want the value "b" to be checked and thereby unchecking the other values. But when I run the code, it just uncheck all the values.
How can I achieve this using jQuery

Comment: Is that wrapped inside a `form`? If ya, just use input type reset.  https://jsfiddle.net/2okpwafw/  Otherwise, you could use: https://jsfiddle.net/2okpwafw/1/

Comment: change `.attr` to `.prop` see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery

Comment: @Wolff, that will reset all the form values if he has more inputs in the form and I guess he wants to reset only the radio box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not always possible to use input type reset. So, you need for the first:

- save the currently checked radio index
- set checked this radio when you click on the link:

```js
$(function () {
  $("a").data('radio-checked-index', $(':radio:checked').index(':radio'));
  $("a").click(function(){
    var checkedIndex =  +$("a").data('radio-checked-index');
    $(':radio:eq(' + checkedIndex + ')').prop('checked', true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="radio" name="field" value="a" />
    <input type="radio" name="field" value="b" checked />
    <input type="radio" name="field" value="c" />
    <input type="reset">
    <a href="javascript:;">cancel</a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
**Edited**

JAVASCRIPT :

```
$("a").click(function(){
   $('input[name="field"][value="b"]').attr('checked', true);
});
```

HTML :

```
<input type="radio" name="field" value="a" />
<input type="radio" name="field" value="b" checked />
<input type="radio" name="field" value="c" />
<a href="javascript:;">cancel</a>
```

Comment: I think you missed a quotation mark in there somewhere.

Comment: what do u mean by `stops` ?

Comment: If you click it a second time , this checked value doesn't reset to "b"